# can i extract updatedAt from document in mongodb&

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

[image]

my document looks like this and I try to get updatedAt from it, but it doesn't even return (the entire document is returned except for it)

```
    db = get_db()
    collection = db['products']
    item = collection.find_one({"id": '02060298-401'})
    item['_id'] = 0
    return item
```

Comment: Is there more than one document with `id='02060298-401'`? What  does `collection.count_documents({"id": '02060298-401'})` return?

Comment: @MichaelRuth no more, function returns 1

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The query returns the document, including `updatedAt`. Please provide more detail on how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you provide some minimal code that will reproduce the problem?